Retrieving user-based email alert data in Salesforce
How can I find out in which email alerts a related use in Salesforce is assigned to the "Recipients" field.
I want to know in which email alerts a related user in Salesforce is a recipient, how can I get a list of this.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Download the Workflow metadata type into your IDE (Workflow includes the Email Alerts)
Then, search the file(s) for this pattern:
<alerts>
    <fullName>Notify_XXX_team</fullName>
    <ccEmails>yyy@foo.com</ccEmails>
    <description>Alert description</description>
    <protected>false</protected>
    <recipients>
        <recipient>joe.blow@example.com</recipient>
        <type>user</type>    <======= here
    </recipients>
    <senderAddress>no-reply@mycompany.com</senderAddress>
    <senderType>OrgWideEmailAddress</senderType>
    <template>Support/My_Template</template>
</alerts>

The <recipients> tag with sub-tag <type> identifies the nature of the recipient. There are a variety of possible values:

accountTeam—Only applicable on the Account object. The email is sent to everyone on that Account’s account team.

campaignMemberDerivedOwner—Emails are sent to lead and contact owners when contacts are added to a campaign or in response to a campaign.

contactLookup—The email is sent to a contact whose value is looked up from a field on the record. For this value, the field field must reference a Contact.

creator—The email is sent to the record’s creator.

customerPortalOwner—The email is sent to a specific self-service portal user. For this value, the recipient field must reference a self-service portal user by their username.

email—The email is sent to an email address whose value is looked up from a field on the record. For this value, the field field must reference an email field.

group—The email is sent to all users in a group. For this value, the recipient field must reference a group by group name.

opportunityTeam—Only applicable on the Opportunity object. The email is sent to everyone on that Opportunity’s opportunity team.

owner—The email is sent to the record’s owner.

partnerUser—The email is sent to a specific partner user. For this value, the recipient field must reference a partner user by username.

portalRole - Like role, but for portal roles only.

portalRoleSubordinates - Like roleSubordinates, but for portal roles only.
role—The email is sent to all users in a role. For this value, the recipient field must reference a role name in the role hierarchy.

roleSubordinates—The email is sent to all users in a role subordinate. For this value, the recipient field must reference a role.

roleSubordinatesInternal—Like roleSubordinates, but for internal portal roles only.

user—The email is sent to a specific user. For this value, the recipient field must reference a user by username.

userLookup—The email is sent to a user whose value is looked up from a field on the record. For this value, the field field must reference a user foreign key field.


Hi cropredy,
First of all, thank you very much for your answer, I was able to obtain the data as you stated, but is there any chance to obtain this data in Apex Class?

You could call the Metadata API and fetch the Workflow metadata type and then parse the XML
